# .Net Core MVC App run in Visual Studio Code can't find views

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have created a new .Net Core MVC web app in Visual Studio 2015. The IDE is fully updated, and I have the latest .net core SDK installed. It consists of the solution file and multiple project files. I can successfully run it and get to the home page.

I have then opened up the root folder (solution folder) in Visual Studio Code and attempted to run it. It seems to start ok, however it can't find the default view for "Views/Home/Index.cshtml".

I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

The program.cs file is as follows:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

The project.json has the following:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
}
```

I imagine this is due to where it is trying to look for the views, as I am at a solution level, not a project level from within VSC.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Does your project.json has preserveCompilationContext in buildOptions?

Comment: @Sanket yes, "preserveCompilationContext": true

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same scenario as well:

1. Opened solution folder from VS Code.
2. Added the suggested build configuration:

[image: Suggested build config]

At this point you can compile and run the project, but it fails in finding the views, as you say.

The solution I've found is to edit the current working directory (`cwd` property) configuration in `.vscode\launch.json`:

[image: Default config]

And make it to point into the Web project folder:

[image: fixed config]

Where the `WebProject` folder is equivalent to `Project root` in the previous answer's example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

.Net core projects have different default routing path then it was with ASP.NET 4.5 (MVC5) projects.

Lets say that your default route in *Startup.cs* file is this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

You want your user to access a view that is Index action for Home controller, e.g. http://mysite/Home/Index

Your directory structure would need to be

- Solution root

  - src

    - Project root

      - Views

        - Home

          - Index.cshtml

In case this is not working for you, check the startup file and see if your default route matches the one from my example.

Comment: My directory structure and default route match yours exactly. And as I say, it works when running it from Visual Studio. But not from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: When you say running from VS Code you probably mean that Visual Studio (full version) is starting the project in IIS Express, and VS Code is starting the embedded Microsoft Kestrel server.

Do you get info whether the project in kestrel is running as development or production (should see it in the command prompt console)

Comment: I believe so. I run it in debug mode from both VS and VSC. And Program.cs is set up to "UseKestrel" and "UseIISIntegration"

Comment: Ok. Can you check the following then. 

Inside your project, do you have a Properties folder with a launchSettings.json inside?

Here is the example how my file looks like [Example](http://pastebin.com/BbvGnACY)

Comment: Yup, and it matches yours exactly (except project name)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I had to do is go to my project path and type `dotnet build` to generate the path of my new added views into `project.razor.json` file. I think in Visual Studio, its generated automatically because we do the thing using an UI.